# REACT creating a basic application where I can set a value

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to REACT and I followed a tutorial where I create a generic app where you can increase / decrease the value.

the html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,700">
  <!-- Code by Angela Delise  
 https://codepen.io/angeladelise/pen/zYKpRqE
 -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

the css:

```
/*   color variables */
$clr-negative: #ff1744;
$clr-positive: #2abf77;
$clr-gray100: #f0f7f8;
$clr-gray200: #cfd8dc;
$clr-gray300: #a7b7be;
$clr-gray400: #6b7e86;
$clr-gray500: #425a65;

/*   border radius */
$radius: 0.2rem;

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: $clr-gray100;
  color: $clr-gray500;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.button__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;

  & > * {
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px $clr-gray200;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: inherit;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
    height: 4rem;
    width: 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 250ms ease-in-out, transform 50ms ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
      background-color: $clr-gray200;
    }

    &:active {
      transform: scale(0.9);
    }

    &:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px $clr-gray500;
    }
  }
}

.negative {
  color: $clr-negative;
  animation: pulse 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.positive {
  color: $clr-positive;
  animation: pulse 500ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

JS:

```
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {
        // if else statement to determine color of the counter
      }
      <h1 className={count > 0 ? "positive" : count < 0 ? "negative" : null}>
        {count}
      </h1>
      <div className="button__wrapper">
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I modify/build from this code and add a text box where I can enter my own value from where it will start from  and then have an additional button that I can click to assign that value.

I am not entirely sure on how to implement this feature

Comment: so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to assign the value from the input then you should use `uncontrolled` input and get the value of the input using `useRef` hook on button click.

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
export default function App() {
    const inputRef = useRef();                // CHANGE
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const assignCustomInput = () => {         // CHANGE
        const value = inputRef.current.value;
        setCount(+value);
    };

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <div className="custom-input-wrapper">        // CHANGE
                <input type="number" ref={inputRef} />
                <button onClick={assignCustomInput}>Assign</button>
            </div>
            <h1 className={count > 0 ? "positive" : count < 0 ? "negative" : null}>
                {count}
            </h1>
            <div className="button__wrapper">
                <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count - 1)}>-</button>
                <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have to create an controlled input for that as shown in below:

```
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const handleChange = (evt) => {
       setCount(evt.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {
        // if else statement to determine color of the counter
      }
      <input type="number" value={count} onChange={handleChange} />
      <h1 className={count > 0 ? "positive" : count < 0 ? "negative" : null}>
        {count}
      </h1>
      <div className="button__wrapper">
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```